# Tailwindcss - How to add top/bottom/right/left in group-hover utilities

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

There are a `<img>` tag and `<button>` tag in a `div`. Use `group` in the div `className` and `group-hover:opacity-0` in `img` tag, it's work properly but `group-hover:top-1/2` in `<button>` tag  doesn't work.

```
<div className="group relative bg-white">
<img
  src={restaurant}
  alt="A website image."
  className="group-hover:opacity-0"
/>
<button
  className="absolute -top-96 group-hover:top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2"
>
  LEARN MORE
</button>
```

I add the given code on the `tailwind.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    extend: {
      top: ['group-hover'],
    }
  },
}
```

how can I solve this????

Comment: I haven't used tailwind before, but looking at their docs, `top` is not a valid variant to be extended: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuring-variants#default-variants-reference
Putting your code in their playground also gives an error: https://play.tailwindcss.com/

Comment: same error sends by vscode 'not valid variant',  but there is any to add 'group-hover:top-1/2'  and it's work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Change `top` in your config to `inset` as [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left#variants) says

> You can control which variants are generated for the top, right, bottom, left, and inset utilities by modifying the inset property in the variants section of your tailwind.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    extend: {
      inset: ['group-hover'],
    }
  },
}
```

**Note:** if you're using Tailwind v2.1+ with `mode: 'jit'` it should generate on the fly no need in extra variants

Comment: install tailwind-css in my react-app following the  documentation given by tailwind-css, the link is: [https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app]   and package.json devDependencies file are given below`"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "tailwindcss-selection-variant": "^0.1.0"
  }`

Comment: Run `npx tailwindcss --help` it will show version of Tailwind among other options

Comment: @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat 2.1.4 and it workes properly